# Derived List to Base IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable, .net-2.0

I have the following code that compiles in .NET Framework version 4.0 and above:

```
public abstract class MyBase { }
public class MyDerived : MyBase { }

public abstract class MyBaseCollection<T> : IList<T> where T : MyBase
{
    protected readonly IList<T> deriveds = new List<T>();

    public void Test()
    {
        // This line works in .NET versions 4.0 and above, but not in versions below.
        IEnumerable<MyBase> bases = deriveds;
    }

    #region IList members with NotImplementedException
    // ...
    #endregion
}
public class MyDerivedCollection : MyBaseCollection<MyDerived> { }
```

But in .NET Framework below 4.0 I get a compile error on the following line:

```
IEnumerable<MyBase> bases = deriveds;
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Question is what has changed (or was introduced) in .NET 4.0 regarding this?
Is there any documentation about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .Net 4.0 the `IEnumerable<T>` interface was changed from:

`public interface IEnumerable<T>`

To

`public interface IEnumerable<out T>`

Notice that the word out has been added to the generic type parameter. This means that the generic parameter is co-variant which means you can pass in a more derived type.

> Covariance Enables you to use a more derived type than originally
>   specified. You can assign an instance of IEnumerable
>   (IEnumerable(Of Derived) in Visual Basic) to a variable of type
>   IEnumerable

See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information

Answer (score 1):

It's about covariance and contravariance of collections. Check the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) to get more information.

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, several generic interfaces have
>   covariant type parameters; for example: IEnumerable,
>   IEnumerator, IQueryable, and IGrouping. All the
>   type parameters of these interfaces are covariant, so the type
>   parameters are used only for the return types of the members.